# Why doesn't the sunlight make noises on home satellite dishes?

Tags: electromagnetism, sun, noise

One of my friends asked me a question to which I could not find a clear answer. We know that the sunlight spectrum includes the entire wave frequencies including those (of the order of 1 GHz) that our home satellite dishes receive from the satellites revolving around the earth. However, I have not ever seen/heard that there are noises on TV as home dishes face the sun. Why?

Is it possible that home dishes never face the sun during the entire day?!

Comment: Have you looked at the *amount* of radiation in the relevant part of the spectrum for sunlight and compared it to the typical sensitivity of a satellite receiver? I don't really understand why you'd reach for the outlandish idea of satellite dishes somehow "never facing the sun".

Comment: @ACuriousMind No, I have not. What about you?! Have you compared the sensitivity of the receiver to the amount of radiation in the relevant part of the sun's spectrum?

Comment: Compare fm radio reception, day vs night. Also remember that the receiver is locking in on a carrier frequency and the modulation around that frequency.

Comment: @ACuriousMind had the right question, you should check some rather obvious orders of magnitude; he already has, so to speak.

Comment: @JonCuster what you seem to be referring to is not really caused by atmospheric noise because there is not much importance of that kind around 100MHz, but the difference between day time and night time *propagation* below 30MHz and that is an AM band, not FM.

Comment: Consider how many orders of magnitude lower 1 GHz is compared with the frequency of the visible peak of the Sun’s spectrum, and how Planck’s Law depends on frequency.

Comment: I don’t understand the down votes. The sun is not well approximated as a black body at microwave frequencies. The effective radiation temperature can be quite high. I’ll try and write an answer when I’m on a computer (on mobile now)

Comment: My point is that receivers process the wavelength range to separate signals from background. Unless the signal is completely overwhelmed by noise one can ignore it. Your fm radio does not care if the sun is shining or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the biggest factor to consider here is that the sun's spectrum at microwave frequencies is not well approximated as a black body.

[image: Solar Flux Density vs. Wavelength]

(Image from [Solar Brightness Temperature and Corresponding Antenna Noise Temperature at Microwave Frequencies](https://ipnpr.jpl.nasa.gov/progress_report/42-175/175E.pdf))

As can be seen in the figure, at frequencies below about 30 GHz (where most satellite to terrestrial TV links live) the sun deviates significantly from the reference blackbody response.  The value is rather frequency dependent and varies with the level of solar activity.

For purposes of assessing the impact to a satellite link, brightness temperature is more useful than flux density.

[image: Solar Brightness Temperature vs. Frequency]

(Image from [Solar Brightness Temperature and Corresponding Antenna Noise Temperature at Microwave Frequencies](https://ipnpr.jpl.nasa.gov/progress_report/42-175/175E.pdf))

From the above figure we see that, even for a quiet sun, the solar brightness temperature at 10 GHz is approximately 10,000 K.

I'm now going to assume that the combination of antenna and receiver for the satellite TV service has a noise temperature of 1000 K (if anyone knows of a good reference I can update my answer.).

This means that if you were trying to look at a satellite in the same direction as the sun the interfering signal from the sun would be about 10x the internal self noise of the receiver and degrade the signal-to-noise ratio (SNR) by about 10 dB.

Fortunately, this doesn't happen all of the time as the antenna has a bit of directivity resulting in spatial selectivity when the satellite is not in front of the sun.  This allows for a higher gain portion of the [antenna pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiation_pattern) to be directed at the satellite and lower gain [sidelobes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sidelobes) to face the sun, suppressing the solar interference relative to the desired signal.

There's also the additional consideration that this link is digital. As there is redundancy and error correction the messaging, as SNR reduces you usually won't notice a corresponding degradation until it is so low that the received signal drops out and you'll see artifacts like pixelation in the receive image.

Answer (score 0):

For a blackbody spectrum with a peak at 5800K: although the energy content at higher and lower frequencies falls off pretty steeply from that peak, there is still enough energy in broadband RF noise from the sun to screw up satellite downlink operation, where the ground stations have to reliably pick up relatively weak signals from the satellites. See hyportnex's comments below. I encourage him to post his commentary as an answer, in which case I will delete mine.

Comment: no self-respecting satellite terminal designer would ever allow his *dish* look directly into the sun, this is what we have sidelobes for.

Comment: @hyportnex, are you telling me that a downlink receiving antenna system could be blown up by the RF output of the sun? please explain so I can edit as appropriate. -NN

Comment: It would not blow up the hardware but would blind the receiver link and screw the SNR, especially the one from a geostationary satellite, those are really weak links. Look for "sun transit outage". From Roddy: Satellite Communications "3.7 Sun Transit Outage Another event which must be allowed for during the equinoxes is the transit of the satellite between earth and sun (see Fig. 3.8), such that ...

Comment: ....the sun comes within the beamwidth of the earth-station antenna. When this happens, the sun appears as an extremely noisy source which completely blanks out the signal from the satellite. This effect is termed sun
transit outage, and it lasts for short periods—each day for about 6 days around the equinoxes. The occurrence and duration of the sun transit outage depends on the latitude of the earth station, a maximum outage time of 10 min being typical."

Comment: This is why satellite links are configured so that the high-gainmain lobe of the earth station antenna looks at the satellite while the sun should be almost always in its much lower gain sidelobes. If that cannot be done then they try to switch beams to a different satellites, if possible. This is less of a problem for LEO links that are stronger and are moving.

Comment: @hyportnex, excellent info, will edit. -NN

Comment: Doesn't fall so steeply on the low side, and the effective temperature of a typical microwave receiver front end is ~60K, so the Sun quite hot for radio. Below a few GHz, synchrotron radiation dominates thermal radiation, so the Sun's effective temperature is even hotter.